# Provisioning Vagrant box with Chocolatey causes node.exe to not be found while running webdriver

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd, vagrant, chocolatey

I am trying to configuring a Windows 7 Vagrant box to run tests.

I used Chocolatey in the provisioning to install all the dependencies needed and everything is *almost* ready, but I keep running into this error when trying to run `webdriver-manager update`, right before the last step, which would be to launch the Selenium server with `webdriver-manager start --detach`:

```
(...)
==> tests: Running provisioner: webdriver-update (shell)...
    tests: Running: provisioners/windows/webdriver-update.bat as C:\tmp\vagrant-shell_05.bat
==> tests: C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager" update
==> tests: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
==> tests: operable program or batch file.
The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

C:\tmp\vagrant-shell_05.bat

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

If I then make a remote connection to the VM after all the provisioning, open a command prompt and run `webdriver-manager update` and `webdriver-manager start` will run successfully, but during provisioning, the problem always occurs.

Sorry for asking a question with so much code but I'm trying to make it as complete as possible:
Here's the `Vagrantfile` I'm using to configure the VM:

```
  config.vm.define "tests", autostart: false do |tests|
    tests.vm.box = 'C:/Users/Bruno Finger/Win7-WinRM.box'
    tests.vm.guest = :windows

    tests.vm.provision "chocolatey",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_01.ps1",
      path: "provisioners/windows/chocolatey-installer.ps1"

    tests.vm.provision "dependencies",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_02.bat",
      path: "provisioners/windows/test-env-dependencies.bat"

    tests.vm.provision "firewall-off",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      run: "always",
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_03.bat",
      path: "provisioners/windows/windows-firewall-off.bat"

    tests.vm.provision "protractor-installer",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_04.bat",
      path: "provisioners/windows/protractor-install.bat"

    tests.vm.provision "webdriver-update",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_05.bat",
      path: "provisioners/windows/webdriver-update.bat"

    tests.vm.provision "webdriver-start",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      run: "always",
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_06.bat",
      path: "provisioners/windows/webdriver-start.bat"

    tests.vm.provision "hosts",
      type: "shell",
      preserve_order: true,
      privileged: true,
      upload_path: "C:/tmp/vagrant-shell_07.ps1",
      path: "provisioners/windows/hosts.ps1"

    tests.vm.communicator = "winrm"
    tests.vm.boot_timeout = 600

    tests.winrm.username = "IEUser"
    tests.winrm.password = "Passw0rd!"

    tests.vm.base_mac = "08002799B15F"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    config.vm.synced_folder "./tests", "/Users/IEUser/DGuardWeb/tests"

    tests.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.gui = true

      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--pae", "on"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 2048]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "90"]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--audio", "none"]
    end
  end
```

The provisioners specified, one by one:

**chocolatey:** (PowerShell script)

```
(iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')))>$null 2>&1

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\RefreshEnv.cmd
```

**dependencies:** (Batch)

```
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe" install -y googlechrome firefox git nodejs.install javaruntime python ruby 7zip selenium-ie-driver

"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\RefreshEnv.cmd"
```

**firewall-off:** (Batch)

```
"C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe" advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

**protractor-installer:** (Batch)

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" install -g protractor

"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\RefreshEnv.cmd"
```

**webdriver-update:** (Batch) *FAILS HERE*

```
"C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager" update
```

**webdriver-start:** (Batch) *Never got to here, but it's supposed to start the Selenium server in background*

```
"C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager" start --detach
```

And finally, here's the **complete** terminal output when I run `vagrant up tests` command: http://pastebin.com/SEfSiG9h

Comment: Great start down that automation chain. But are you sure it's Chocolatey causing this file not to be found? Note it could be something in `refreshenv` that is overriding something that was added to the temporary path, but not to the persistent path.

Comment: @ferventcoder I removed all calls to `refreshenv` as you suggested, but I still end up with the same error: `==> tests: C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Users\IEUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager" update
==> tests: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
==> tests: operable program or batch file.`. As it didn't make any difference I rather keep the scripts without this command, but I think `webdriver-manager` is to fault here, as there's no way of telling it where `node.exe` is located, it just assumes it's in the `PATH`.

Comment: If I then make a remote connection to the VM after all the provisioning, open a command prompt and run `webdriver-manager update` and `webdriver-manager start` will run successfully, but during provisioning, the problem always occurs.